# Save data in website create by HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I programmed a website using html, css, js, but when the customer registers his personal information, where can this information be saved without localstorage? in the php language, the data is saved in Mysql, but in this case I have no idea.

Comment: You can use any database you want, including MySQL. Google "databases for web apps".

Comment: There are 100s of options available. You can connect to any SQL or NoSQL database out there, but you will need some server side code to ensure that your secrets remain secret (e.g. Database connection details)

Answer (score 2):

A web application normally has a clientside and a serverside component.

To save data (without using `localStorage`), you would typically do that at serverside. MySQL that you mention is a serverside technology, as is PHP. PHP can't run in a browser; it is only capable of generating the clientside code (i.e. HTML, CSS, JS) that would eventually run on the browser.

JavaScript, HTML and CSS work together to create the clientside part of the app. JavaScript can also be used as a serverside technology, in the guise of Node.js, but most people just use "JavaScript" for the browser-based JavaScript.

(As an aside — There are some services you can use as serverside storage that you don't need to manage yourself, such as Firebase. It is still serverside, though it is not on *your* server.)

Thus, using "using html, css, js" is not exclusive to using PHP (or Python, or Ruby, or Node.js, or indeed any number of available serverside technologies). You typically need both, when you want to store data.